# Handle 422 with $fetch

Tags: nuxtjs3

I'm upgrading a project to Nuxt3 and I'm using the new `$fetch` to hit my API, all it's OK but I can't manage the handle the 422 error from the API.

The API I've created would return something like this for the 422 code

```
{ message:  "The email has already been taken.",  errors: { email: ["The email has already been taken."]}}
```

Then in Nuxt I'm using this:

```
$fetch(`${runtimeConfig.public.BASE_API_BROWSER_URL}/XXX/`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: {
    ...data
  }
})
.then((resp) => {
  message.value.push(resp.message)
  isSubmitting.value = false
})
.catch((error) => {
  errors.value.push(error.message)
  isSubmitting.value = false
})
```

But what I have back is just `FetchError: 422 Unprocessable Content` instead of the error inside the API response, any idea on how to able to use `error.message` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be typically accessible via `error.response.message`.

For better visibility of the error object structure, use [console.dir](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/dir) to explore its contents in the browser console: `console.dir(error)`

> Unlike `console.log(var1, var2, var3)`, `console.dir` only handles one attribute.
>
> **Important to remember this else you will be misled to thinking variables are empty.**

Comment: thanks for the answer, in the end seems I have to pull it like this `error.response._data.message`

Comment: @Sebastiano same for me `_data` in my project, is the backend JAVA Spring REST?; I get the feeling that's typical of that framework as I don't recall accessing errors from the likes of Laravel with an underscore?

Comment: nop, my BE is Laravel